# toggle button on text area click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I want to toggle a Submit `button` visibility when I click on `textarea`.

**HTML**:

```
<textarea id="flow_button_view" name="dessc" class="social_text_area" placeholder="Flow your thinking"></textarea>
<div id="flow_info">
  <button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area" title=" Share Your Flow ">
    <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Post
  </button>                 
</div>
```

when user clicks the `textarea` I want to view the button. My `textarea` uses **tineymce** plugin for edit.

Comment: You want to the "Post" button to be clicked every time you click or type in the textarea?

Comment: Why you can't see the button? Is the div flow_info set to display:none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `blur` and `focus` events on your `<textarea>` initialised as **tinymce**, you need to pass the events upon initialization:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.5.3/tinymce.min.js"></script> 
.....
<textarea id="flow_button_view" name="dessc" class="social_text_area" placeholder="Flow your thinking"></textarea>

<div id="flow_info">
  <button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area" title=" Share Your Flow ">
    <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Post
  </button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#flow_info {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var $info = $("#flow_info");

tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
    editor.on('focus', function (e) {
      $info.show();
    });
    editor.on('blur', function (e) {
      $info.hide();
    });
  }
});
```

working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLasceLj/1/).

Comment: sir there is a problem when I click the post button its not working or hide thanks

Comment: It is whole different functionality, unrelated to question's content provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").focus(function(){
        $("button").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flow_info">
    <textarea id="flow_button_view" name="dessc" class="social_text_area" placeholder="Flow your thinking"></textarea>
  <br>
    <button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area" title=" Share Your Flow " style="display: none;">
    <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Post
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: or in stead of `focus` use the `keypress` event. This will only show the button on changes

Comment: yes good but when i click outside of the textared then the button again hide and many many thanks to you sir

Comment: if you want to hide button when we click outside textarea, then use: `$("textarea").blur(function(){
        $("button").hide();
    });`

Comment: You have to handle it using TinyMCE's event hadlers which are specified while initialising it. posted an answer on how to do that.

Comment: yeah, that's right.. use TinyMCE blur event as explained here: http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.blur

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="flow_button_view" name="dessc" class="social_text_area" placeholder="Flow your thinking"></textarea>
<div id="flow_info"><button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area" id="button" title=" Share Your Flow ">
<i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Post </button>
```

```js
$('#flow_info').hide();
$('#flow_button_view').on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value.length) {
        $('#flow_info').show();
    }else{
        $('#flow_info').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="flow_button_view" name="dessc" class="social_text_area" placeholder="Flow your thinking"></textarea>
<div id="flow_info"><button name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area" id="button" title=" Share Your Flow ">
    <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Post </button>
 </div>
```

by using jquery you can do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#flow_button_view").focus(function() {
   $('#flow_info').show();
}
```

If you want to show the button even if user click outside textbox then you should use one more function that checks if something is written in textbox or not along with focus function 'onkeypress' event helps you to track if user has written something or not.

Comment: Care to explain please.

Comment: OP using tinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but what I think you are asking is how to enable/show a button on click/change of your tinyMCE editor instance.
If that is correct then you can use TinyMCE's handlers to detect state change and other events. You haven't specified which version of TinyMCE you are using, but for 4.x you can use something like the following:

```
tinymce.init({
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('focus', function (e) {  
          alert('Editor is in focus');
          $(".editor_submit_button").show();  // add an id to the button you want to toggle and use it here.          
         });
});
```

Reference: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/

EDIT: updated link